# Why is my IBAction to change the text of a label not working?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to implement a label in my iOS app that changes its value to that of a text field when the user types a new character into the text field.

Hence, I wrote this IB Action in my view controller.
`listenerLabel` is a `UILabel` IBOutlet, and `textInput` is a `UITextField` IBOutlet.

```
- (IBAction)keyboardResponse:(id)sender
{
    listenerLabel.text = textInput.text;
}
```

I then declared it in my header file.

```
- (IBAction)keyboardResponse:(id)sender;
```

Afterwards, in my xib file, I

1. dragged a line from File's Owner to the two UI elements and associated them with the IBOutlets.
2. hit Ctrl and clicked on the text field in the UIBuilder to associate its "Value Changed" action to the IBAction `keyboardResponse`.

However, when I run the app in iOS Simulator, the text of the label does not change as I type letters into the text field. Why not?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint at `listenerLabel.text = textInput.text` to see if that line of code is being executed when you type?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I wrote `NSLog(@"foobar")` after `listenerLabel.text = textInput.text;` and the log message never appeared. I guess the IBAction isn't ever being called. I wonder why. I see the IBAction `keyboardResponse` listed when I Ctrl+Click the text field in my xib.

Comment: NSNotifications are the way to listen to change events for UITextViews

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a notification to do this.  Assuming you have those outlets wired up correctly to both the label and the textfield do this:

in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(myTextChanged)
     name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification 
     object:textInput];
```

Add this method (you don't need those IBActions

```
-(void)myTextChanged {
    self. listenerLabel.text = textInput.text;

}
```

As a side-note - learn to use the Assistant Editor, it eliminates mistakes when wiring up IBActions or IBOutlets and adds in the cleanup in the viewDidUnload automagically.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you choose to use a notification instead of using the textField's delegate since it is in the same view and seems to be exactly what the delegate method was designed for.

Comment: No it's not.  UITextField doesn't have a delegate method for text changed, only didBeginEditing and didEndEditing.  The UISearchBar has a textDidChange, but not UITextField.

Comment: Good point, I missed that.  However, there is still a delegate method for that:  shouldChangeCharactersInRange.  There is nothing wrong with using a notification, but I am curious why you choose it over a delegate method!

Comment: That still doesn't work as the OP intends.  That will lag one character behind.  Did you test this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `UITextFieldDelegate` method that was made just for this.

1. Make your view controller adopt this protocol.  i.e. in your .h file:

   `@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {`
2. In Interface Builder, set the `delegate` of `textInput` to your view controller.
3. Then in your .m file, add the following:  (EDITED)

   ```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
       if (textField == textInput) {
           listenerLabel.text  = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];;
       }
       // Note that if you don't want the characters to change in the textField 
       // you can return NO here:
       return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: That will only happen when you finish editing the textfield, not in real time when the text is changing.  Read the question, the OP wants to have the label change in real time.

Comment: That still doesn't work as the OP intends.  That will lag one character behind.  Did you test this?

Comment: That does work. The only real difference is that approach means you have created an extra object (the NSMutableString object), and you have to set the VC up as a delegate for the TextField.

Comment: Yeah, in my project I was using the mutable string for other purposes and we don't really need it here...  removed